# Why is my bathtub handle difficult to turn?

Tags: bathtub

I moved into a new place, and the bathtub handle in the upstairs bath is very difficult to turn. The bathtub in the other bath downstairs does not have this issue. Handle looks to be a Moen, and there's nothing obviously different about it from the other bathtub in the house or in other houses I've seen.

What could be causing this issue and how can I make the handle easier to turn?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the cartridge may need some plumber's grease .... it may have some mineral buildup

Comment: Yup, pull and grease (or replace) the cartridge : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF5YkOJOz3k

Comment: Bad Cartridge.. turn main house water off and replace cartridge - 20 minute job.